# Open eclipse juno with error “No more handles …” in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, mozilla

Starting today, every time I open up the eclipse, I got a message box with title "Problem Occured" pops up saying:

> No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)] possible args: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}
>   No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]

Then I click "OK" and proceed to the workbench, I got another error saying

> An SWT error has occurred.
>   You are recommended to exit the workbench.
>   Subsequent errors may happen and exit the workbench without warning.
>   See the .log file for more details.
>
> Do you want to exit the workbench? (Yes / No)

Then I clicked "Yes" and took a look at the .log file in .metadata. I saw this long stacktrace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan 4 0 2012-08-25 14:28:52.355
!MESSAGE No resource bundle has been set for the LoggerNo more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan 4 0 2012-08-25 14:28:52.359
!MESSAGE No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)] possible args: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1939)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan.internal.ui.view.GraphicsPlanControl.createDetailForm(GraphicsPlanControl.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan.internal.ui.view.GraphicsPlanControl.init(GraphicsPlanControl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan.internal.ui.view.GraphicsPlanControl.<init>(GraphicsPlanControl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan.internal.ui.view.PlanView.createPartControl(PlanView.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4291)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher$13.widgetSelected(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
!SESSION 2012-08-25 14:48:17.623 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_34
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

I did hours of Google searching, seeing all different solutions, but they are either too complicated for me to figure out [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695271/swt-browser-eclipse), or not work at all.

I tried the following:

1. edit /etc/environment and add `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/firefox`, no effect
2. edit eclipse.desktop and change `Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse/eclipse` to `Exec=env MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/firefox /usr/bin/eclipse/eclipse` this time the eclipse will freeze at the start-up.
3. download a XULRunner-1.9.2.19 from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/1.9.2.19/source/) and set the `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME` env variable point to directory where I extract it. I got a new error:

> ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan 4 0 2012-08-25 14:48:25.509

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan 4 0 2012-08-25 14:48:25.509
!MESSAGE No resource bundle has been set for the LoggerNo more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/mozilla-1.9.2'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /usr/bin/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/626/2/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
    /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
)".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan 4 0 2012-08-25 14:48:25.513
!MESSAGE No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/mozilla-1.9.2'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /usr/bin/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/626/2/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
    /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) possible args: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/mozilla-1.9.2'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /usr/bin/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/626/2/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so
    Can't load library: /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
    /home/simon/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1970)
```

... and then the super long stacktrace

Could anyone please help me figure out how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: nevermind, i removed the workspace as long with the eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

In a shell before you launch eclipse:

find xulrunner:
`sudo updatedb && locate xulrunner | grep '/usr/lib'`

export the environment variable:
`export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner/usr/lib/xulrunner`

launch eclipse

[reference](https://www.jfire.org/modules/phpwiki/index.php/HowToSetupTheIntegratedBrowserOnLinux)

Answer (score 1):

my case is with ubuntu 16.04 just issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```